# mounting CIFS share appears to work, but then prevents writing after a few seconds

Tags: 12.04, permissions, fstab, cifs

I've got a NAS that is setup with CIFS and open guest access.  I mounted it in `fstab` with the following line

```
//192.168.0.101/Stor1 /media/freenasbox cifs guest,rw,**noperm**,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

which appears to work great.  I've got read/write access.

However, I start up Transmission and try to download to `/media/freenasbox` and it appears to successfully download a file for a few seconds, then gives me

```
Error: Permission Denied
```

Also, when I try to create a folder/file in `/media/freenasbox` , Nautilus shows it with a padlock over it, but I can still delete it.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?